# Replacement of an element based upon condition within an array

Tags: coldfusion

I am running code where I am getting the value in the array as:

`URLValue[1]`

This contains code such as:

`a=c&mode=yes&action=right&sortorder=2`

Now I want to make a change. If the `sortorder=2`, it should change that value to `sortorder=1` and vice versa when conditions change, but I could not find any approach to do it.

I checked `arrayFind` but how that will work with an if condition to replace that sortorder with what I am running?

Like checking if the `sortorder=1`, make it 2 and if it is 2 make it 1, so I can make the sorting work properly.

As to why I am doing this, there is a condition as this cannot be done through jQuery.

**Here is an Update#1**

Apparently, the `URLValue[1]` is formed through a URL Query String. So I was thinking why not do a replace like this:

```
<cfif cgi.QUERY_STRING contains 'sortOrder=2'>
    <cfset URLreplace = 'sortOrder=1'>
<cfelse>
    <cfset URLreplace = 'sortOrder=2'>
</cfif>
```

I was thinking of something like `replace` or `replacelist`, but then how do I do the `URLReplace` within the URL and then convert that value into an array?

Comment: What is the overall objective here?  There might be some excessive complication taking place?

Comment: Does SortOrder always come last in the list?

Comment: looks like he is doing a toggle switch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want to do is toggle the sort order value in this specific case then I would just cut to the chase. If you find A replace it with B and vise versa.

```
<cfif findNoCase("sortOrder=1",urlValue[1])>
    <cfset urlValue[1] = ReplaceNoCase(urlValue[1],"sortorder=1","sortorder=2")/>
<cfelseif  findNoCase("sortOrder=2",urlValue[1])>
    <cfset urlValue[1] = ReplaceNoCase(urlValue[1],"sortorder=2","sortorder=1")/>
</cfif>
```

That's IF all you are after is to toggle it. The code above would always replace 1 with 2 where it exists in the URL. Of course you may want to add additional checks to your if statements depending on where this query string is going to end up.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I se experts saying here i am complicating things, i do not want to, but i am working on such a stuff that i need to break the url, and extract couple of its parts and rebuild it again, the best way i found is to do with Rematch adn Arrays so i am going that way,

Comment: Exactly why do you think you need to parse the query string manually? Without more details, it sounds like it could be accomplished more simply by looping through the `URL` structure.

Comment: Based on his question it's not clear that he's using the _actual_ query string Leigh. He only said he had an array key called `URLValue[1]` that was _formed using the query string_. That could mean it is manipulated in other ways. I was giving him a "cut to the chase" solution. If it is indeed the URL scope  boiled down to a var then yes, he should modify it at whatever point it is placed into this var.

Comment: (Edit typo fix) Mark - My remark was actually for bingo, in response to his/her last comment that essentially said "I don't want to.. but I think I have to...". Given that their code uses `CGI.QUERY_STRING`, the parameters are definitely available in the `URL` scope. So resorting to string parsing is most likely an unnecessary over-complication here. Hence my question.

Comment: gotcha. Like a lot of these posts I often want to say _don't_ instead of _here's how_ ... but having written my share of bolted on workaround claptrap code I try not to judge :)

Comment: Yeah, having worked with a lot of legacy apps I know sometimes refactoring is not feasible. But it is hard to tell the difference between those cases and cases where the asker just is not aware there is a better option. Based question, this sounded like the latter case :)

Answer (score 0):

> the `URLValue[1]` is formed through a URL Query String
>   ...
>   `<cfif cgi.QUERY_STRING contains 'sortOrder=2'>`

Dan raises a good point. You may be over complicating things. There should be no need to parse the `CGI.QUERY_STRING` to extract the parameters. The parameters for the *current page* are already parsed and available in the [system scope `URL`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec09af4-7ff1.html).

To modify a URL parameter, simply access it by name, via the URL scope. (If the parameter is optional, use [`structKeyExists`](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/StructKeyExists) to verify it exists first).

```
<cfset URL.sortOrder = URL.sortOrder eq 1 ? 2 : 1>
```

Then if you really need to convert the parameters into an array, just loop through the keys in the `URL` scope/structure:

```
 <cfloop collection="#URL#" item="key">
     <!--- demo - show parameters --->
     <cfoutput>
        Key name = #key# Value = #URL[key]#<br>
     </cfoutput>
     ... do something with the paramters here ...
 </cfloop>
```